# Rails: change column type, but keep data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a model with a column of type `integer` which I want to convert to type `string`. Now I'm looking for the best way to change the column type **without** losing the data. Is there a painless way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this a one-off, or do you want it to repeatedly work, for example, in a migration?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A standard migration using the change_column method will convert integers to strings without any data loss. rake db:rollback will also do the reverse migration without error if required.

Here is the test migration I used to confirm this behaviour:

```
class ChangeAgeToString < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :users, :age, :string
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :users, :age, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work for me. I'm using rails 3.2.13 with mysql 14.14 on a Mac, and the above migration changes all my :integer values to 0

Comment: I've just re-tested with the versions you've mentioned (Rails 3.2.13 and mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.27, for osx10.8 (i386) using readline 5.1). Everything worked as expected. Before migration (=> #<User id: 1, age: 12, created_at: "2013-04-16 13:52:04", updated_at: "2013-04-16 13:52:04">) after migration (=> #<User id: 1, age: "12", created_at: "2013-04-16 13:52:04", updated_at: "2013-04-16 13:52:04">). What did you do differently gardenofwine?

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar as @gardenofwine but converting the column  from `time` to `datetime`. If the original data is "09:30:30", after migration I get all zeros. I'm using Rails 3.2.12 and same version of mysql as @Jon. Any idea how this can happen.

Comment: Converting a time to a datetime isn't quite so simple elhoyos. Which particular date to you expect it to imagine you require for each instance of time it converts during the migration?

Answer (score 5):

for postgres
in migration

```
 change_column :table_name, :field,'boolean USING (CASE field WHEN \'your any string as true\' THEN \'t\'::boolean ELSE \'f\'::boolean END)'
```

and to any valid type similar

Answer (score 5):

for **postgresql**, change table column datatype `integer` to `string`,
`rails migration like this with up and down actions`

```
class ChangeAgeToString < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up  
    change_column :users, :age, 'varchar USING CAST(age AS varchar)', null: false
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :users, :age, 'integer USING CAST(age AS integer)', null: false, default: 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a one-off you can just change the column type in the database (since no info is lost moving from int to varchar)

For MySQL, this would do it:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY col1 VARCHAR(256)
```

If you're using SQLite you won't have to do anything.

Comment: I use postgresql in the current project and it worked as well!

Thanks for your answer, I set the following post as the accepted answer just because I think most users that have this question might need a migration.

Comment: Cool. Yeah, the migration answer is the better one. I was actually at work, working on a MySql DB at the the time, so the database answer appeared to me first!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'integer USING CAST(column_name AS integer)'
```

or even better:

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, :integer, using: 'column_name::integer'
```

You can read more about this topic here: https://kolosek.com/rails-change-database-column

Answer (score 1):

If you use Postgres, you can't implicitly cast a string back to an integer, so the way to make the change reversible is:

```
class ChangeAgeToString < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :users, :age, :string
  end

  def self.down
    add_column :age_integer
    User.connection.execute('UPDATE users SET age_integer = cast(age as int)')
    remove_column :users, :age
    rename_column :users, :age_integer, :age
  end
end
```